# Convert Week Number to First day of Week

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, week-number

I have a table with a column containing a date. My goal is to group by week, using the first day of the week (monday). Currently, I have it grouping only by week number and I cannot figure out how to get week number to convert to the date of the week begin. Current code:

```
SELECT 
        DATEPART(week, CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/Denver', fact_completed_offer_engagements.verified)) AS "fact_completed_offer_engagements.verified_date",
        COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN fact_completed_offer_engagements.activated IS NOT NULL THEN fact_completed_offer_engagements.customer_offer_id ELSE NULL END) AS "fact_completed_offer_engagements.shopping_list_placements"
FROM public.fact_completed_offer_engagements AS fact_completed_offer_engagements
LEFT JOIN public.offers AS offers ON fact_completed_offer_engagements.offer_id = offers.id
LEFT JOIN public.campaigns AS campaigns ON offers.campaign_id = campaigns.id
LEFT JOIN public.contracts AS contracts ON campaigns.contract_id = contracts.id

  WHERE 
    (campaigns.id = ?)
                OR campaigns.id = ?
group by 1
ORDER BY 1
limit 1000
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I added the sql-server tag because it looks a lot like SQL Server code.

Comment: Do you have a date table?

Comment: Is this question solved? Do you need further help? Please allow me one hint: It would be very kind of you to tick the acceptance check below the best answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you crossed the 15 points border yourself you are - additionally - asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38601630/5089204

Be aware, that you are using culture specific logic. The first day of week is Monday, but not everywhere...

Use `@@DATEFIRST` to calculate a culture independant date like this

```
DECLARE @testDate DATETIME=GETDATE();
SELECT @testDate - (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(WEEKDAY,@testDate)) % 7 + 1;
```

The result is always the Sunday before the date given. Add `+2` at the end and you'll get your Monday.

### UPDATE

You might want to cast the result to `DATE` in order to get rid of the time component...

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate week commencing date using the following sequence generation and aggregation CTEs. Just join your query to it on week number and alter the start date to match your requirements.

```
-- Set fist day of week as Monday
SET DATEFIRST 1;

;WITH CTE_Nums AS (
              SELECT    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ob.object_id) AS Num
              FROM      sys.all_objects AS ob
             ),
CTE_WeekBegin AS (
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, Num, '2016-01-01')) AS WeekNo, MIN(DATEADD(DAY, Num, '2016-01-01')) AS Date
FROM CTE_Nums
GROUP BY DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, Num, '2016-01-01'))
)
SELECT wb.Date, ...
FROM ...
INNER JOIN CTE_WeekBegin wb ON wb.WeekNo = xx.xx;
```